# Using cookieStore: Cannot read property "put" of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, cookiestore

For some reason I'm having trouble using `cookieStore`.  I'm adding it to my app in routes.js with:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngCookies']);
```

and then trying to use it in my `TabCtrl` as such:

```
myApp.controller('TabsCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope, $cookieStore) {
  $cookieStore.put('tab', '#/dashboard/summary');
```

and I get **"Cannot read property 'put' of undefined"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only injecting `$scope` into your controller but expecting `$scope` and `$cookieStore`. Add `$cookieStore` to your dependencies and make sure you've got your closing brackets (square and regular). You might have this already but you haven't posted all your code!

So change:

```
myApp.controller('TabsCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope, $cookieStore) {
```

to...

```
myApp.controller('TabsCtrl', ['$scope', '$cookieStore', function ($scope, $cookieStore) {
```